# PHP - Getting Text From Inside Class

Tags: php

I'm attempting to gather text from a webpage using PHP, so that when the text on that website is updated, it's also automatically updated.

Take the site http://www.roblox.com/CW-Ultimate-Amethyst-Addiction-item?id=188004500 for example - inside the class `robux-text`, there's a figure saying R$ 20,003 - my aim is to get that text from Roblox, to my site.

I have attempted this using the code, but to no avail - I'm being presented with the following errors:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in
>   /home/public_html/index.php on line 9
>
> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://www.roblox.com/CW-Ultimate-Amethyst-Addiction-item?id=188004500):
>   failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Temporary failure in name resolution in /home/public_html/index.php on
>   line 9
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in /home/public_html/index.php on line 11

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.roblox.com/CW-Ultimate-Amethyst-Addiction-item?id=188004500");
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($DOM);
$classname = 'robux-text';
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  echo $node->nodeValue;
}
?>
```

Comment: You code looks ok, the problem seems to be related with the domain name resolution of www.roblox.com

Comment: Is there any solution around this?

Comment: Maybe try it via curl, if you set the returntransfer option, you should get the html source of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `allow_url_fopen` is **disabled** your system (`php.ini`), that's why you're getting the error.

Try it with [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.roblox.com/CW-Ultimate-Amethyst-Addiction-item?id=188004500");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($DOM);
$classname = 'robux-text';
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  echo $node->nodeValue;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was receiving errors at first with this code, but after adding libxml_use_internal_errors(true);, the text is showing and there's no errors. Many thanks!

Comment: good! you're finally getting the page html :) They're just warnings, you can safely ignore them, I've updated my answer with `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`

Comment: Just out of query, there's more than one robux-text class on the url I provided - is there a way to make it only grab the text from the first robux-text class?

Comment: you can try to use `$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");  echo $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue` without the foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you, that's brilliant - I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You're very welcome @Barbra.Higgins   :) If my answer helped you, please consider vote 1+, tks !

Comment: don't worry about it, tks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the html content of an url easily via curl. You just have to set the returntransfer option to true.